# Как трансформировать класс с помощью ClassTransformer?

Tags: java, ооп, gradle

У меня есть готовый ClassTransformer, который мне нужно вызывать исключительно при вызове метода startProfiling. При этом в premain я указала, чтобы трансформер был демоном и ждал выполнения условий. У меня есть задачи, исполнение которых я вызываю в виде потоков, и мне нужно при вызове метода startProfiling добавить к ним время исполнения. Задачи вызываются классом Tasks, но вызываются они и вне метода startProfiling, а трансформер, если мы находимся в классе Tasks начинает менять вывод, хотя мне это пока не нужно (пока я startProfiling не вызвала).

Как разрешить эту проблему? Пробовала ставить флаг в метод startProfiling, добавлять трансформеру еще проверку флага на true, но он просто его не видит.

Вот код классов ClassTransformer, Premain:

```
public class ClassTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

@Override
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader,
                        String className,
                        Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
                        ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
                        byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

    System.out.println(className);
    try {
        if (className.equals("jmx/Tasks")) {
            ClassPool classPool = new ClassPool();
            classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(loader));
            CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));
            CtMethod[] methods = ctClass.getMethods();

            for( CtMethod method : methods){
                if (method.getName().equals("run")){
                    System.out.println("Entering "+ method.getName() + " of " + className);
                    method.addLocalVariable("elapsedTime", CtClass.longType);
                    method.insertBefore("elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();");
                    method.insertAfter("{elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime;"
                            + "System.out.println(\"[profiling]Execution time was: \" + elapsedTime);}");
                } }
            return ctClass.toBytecode();
        }
        else {
            return classfileBuffer;
        } }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    } } }

public class Premain {
public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    instrumentation.addTransformer(new ClassTransformer());
} }
```

Метод startProfiling:

```
@Override
public void startProfiling(String name, String mainClass) {
    if (Tasks.statusStore.get(name + "|" +  mainClass  + ".class").equals(Thread.State.RUNNABLE)) {
        var classpath = Tasks.classpathStore.get(name + "|" +  mainClass  + ".class");
        cancel(name, mainClass);
        try {
            isProfiling = true;
            submit(name, Tasks.classpathStore.get(name + "|" + mainClass + ".class"),
                    mainClass, periodStore.get(name + "|" + mainClass + ".class"));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("\nTask <" + name + "> not found...\n");
        } } else {
        System.out.println("\nTask <" + name + "> is not in a state of execution!\n");
    } }
```